# Unable to select a particular host from inventory file in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I went through a tutorial to transfer files between two servers directly using synchronize command and I am trying to transfer a file from source to destination where source will have 1 server and destination will have multiple servers in the inventory file as seen below:

```
[source]
server_1

[destination]
server_2
server_3
server_4
```

and based on a specific condition, I will select which server I will "synchronize push" to transfer the file. But I tried many methods to extract the server but I am unable to even pick a host:

```
-hosts: "{{ groups['destination'][0] }}"

-hosts: "{{destination.0}}"

-hosts: "{{destination[0]}}"
```

Those all throw me the below error:

> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - hosts: "{{ destination }}"
>   ^ here
>
> We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes. Always quote
> template expression brackets when they start a value. For instance:
>
> ```
> with_items:
>   - {{ foo }}
> ```
>
> Should be written as:
>
> ```
> with_items:
>   - "{{ foo }}"
> ```

How do I select the destination server from inventory file in ansible playbook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to use Inventory group [destination] in playbook.

> hosts: "{{ destination }}"
> ^ here

This should be without bracket instead of.

> hosts: destination

And if you want to run on specific match host then

> hosts: destination[2:3]

Also you can use delegate if you want to run task to specific host.

> delegate_to: {{ hostname }}